# Organize directories for applications with front-end and back-end in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-modules

I am using technique to separate back end from front end in yii using following directory structure:
wwwroot/

```
index.php
backend.php
assets/
images/
js/
protected/
    config/
        main.php
    components/
    controllers/
    models/
    views/
    runtime/
    backend/
        config/
            main.php
        components/
        controllers/
        models/
        views/
        runtime/
```

Ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/33/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end/

Problem is, I am not understanding how would we use Yii::app->createUrl() or Yii::app->createAbsoluteUrl() in back end for front end urls.

e.g Yii::app->createUrl('home/index') will echo "/backend/home/index"  in back end controllers/views but i want it to echo like this /home/index which is for front end controller/view.

Please help me out with any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the technique described in that wiki document, you should create a [module](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module) for your back end instead of trying to run two separate applications.

This way your back end can share your models and components, but the controllers, views and any unique models are still kept separate.

Then you can just go:

```
$this->createUrl('backend/mycontroller',array('id'=>100));
```

When you need to create a URL from a controller.

Comment: Thanx for the better advice. But, I am in middle of work. and already have done a lot of work on this technique but stuck on this.

Comment: It shouldn't take much more than picking up your controllers + views and placing them in a module. I assume you already share models?

Comment: I think in the comments there are some hacks which will solve your problem, but I think it'd definitely be worth modifying your application to use modules properly before you invest more development time then run into another issue it causes. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/33/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end/#c4085

Comment: Yes, I have shared my models, components and extensions of frontend with backend.

Comment: I think if you put the backend directory in a directory called modules, remove the config, components and runtime directories from backend then add the appropriate module configuration in the root config it should pretty much work.

Comment: I have moved the backend dir in module and removed config, components and runtime directories from backend . But how would i configure it in root config?

Comment: Follow the instructions in that module documentation link I provided. By root config I mean the config under protected/config rather than protected/backend/config.

Comment: I followed, but following error "Alias "backend.BackendModule" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable." is coming on hitting http://yii.local/backend/

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the answer as correct if that ended up solving your problem ;)